# How to export image from MSSQL and display it on a website?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm having some difficulties getting this to work.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
require_once('db_connection.php');
$Query = mssql_query("SELECT Photo FROM Persons WHERE IDPerson = '3'");
$Person = mssql_fetch_array($Query);
$Photo = $Person["Photo"];
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $Photo;
```

This is the result I'm getting:

[image]

> (There is something showing up on the bottom of the image, but that's
>   only part of the image)

This is how the image value looks like in my database:

> 0x424D3684030000000000360000002800000040010000F000000001001800000000000084030000000000000000000000000000000000FDFEF5FCFDF4FFFFFAE3F2DA
>   .......

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try echo $Photo?

Comment: Yes sorry, I was testing something it should be $Photo there it's still not working tho.

Comment: what is the data type of `Photo` column?

Comment: What's the length of the string you're getting? If memory serves, blob types are affected by mssql.textlimit and mssql.textsize.

Comment: I've managed to display half of the image before so now I went to php.ini and changed both of those properties to 16386 (from default: 4096), restarted the web server but the problem remains, there is only a half of image displayed.

Comment: So I found out that I had 3 php.ini files and didn't know which one was being used so I changed those properties in all files and now it seems to be working. Thanks cleong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have to use use base64 encoding to display image from database

like

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAWgBaAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlubwIQAAB..." />
```

**use, base64 encoding**

```
<?php
$Query = mssql_query("SELECT Photo FROM Persons WHERE IDPerson = '3'");
$Person = mssql_fetch_array($Query);
$Photo = $Person["Photo"];

$mime = null;
// place $type init. here
if ($type=="pjpeg") // <<< where do you get $type btw?
    $mime = "image/jpeg";

$b64Src = "data:".$mime.";base64," . base64_encode($Photo);
echo '<img src="'.$b64Src.'" alt="" />';
?>
```

**for example**

```
header("Content-type: image/png");

echo base64_decode('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');
```

if your string like this, it will print pdf logo

Comment: I know the type = image/jpeg, I tried your code and it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: is your database content value some thing like QSkZJRgABAQEAWgBaAAD/4gxYS

Comment: I've edited my original post and added how my image value looks like in my database you can see it at the bottom of the post.

Comment: how you store image in your DB ? using file get content ? or any other ?

Comment: File is being stored though a Visual Basic 6 program. I'm not exactly sure if the image type is jpeg? Any way to figure out how this image is encoded without having to figure out how the program works?

Comment: you have to define mysql column data type  like  `image` blob NOT NULL, means datatype should be blob

Comment: Its not as simple as that, I cannot just change the database I can only read its contents. So what you are saying is that I cannot display this data as a jpg images no matter what? I've searched all over the internet for an answer and tried a lot of ways to get it working but no luck. So is it impossible?

Comment: i have added one example at the end of my answer. pls try and see

Comment: I tried the example code and it seems to be working I get an Adobe document icon or something like that?

Comment: yes it correct so might have problem in your database string to display image from database. if you are able to store this same string in DB and retrive it and print again if possible